# Turning query errors to Exceptions in MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to turn MySQLi query errors to Exceptions, but couldn't - [mysqli_sql_exception](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-sql-exception.php) is thrown only if it failed to connect the DB.

I used `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT)` and procedural MySQLi functions embedded to custom wrapper class.

**Former code:**

```
public function mysqlQuery($SQL) {

    $this->Result = mysqli_query($this->DBlink, $SQL);

    if($this->Result === false)
        throw new MySQLiQueryException($SQL, mysqli_error($this->DBlink), mysqli_errno($this->DBlink));

    return $this->Result;

}
```

**Question:** Is it normal no Warning, nor Exception are thrown when query fails so I have to check if mysqli_query() returned false?

Comment: As far as I know mysqli only throws exception only on DB connect. So ... pretty much, yes. You have mysqli_errno, mysqli_error and other functions so you know the error, but that's the limit.

Comment: You can throw exceptions if sometning goes wrong with just `try, catch, throw`

Comment: @k102, I was trying to put that part to MySQLi from my code.

Comment: @VladPreda I see, seams like I have to leave it as it is now.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Some time ago I managed to sort this matter out. As it was pointed out in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21048373/285587),

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

is a correct way to tell mysqli to throw exceptions.

Just make sure you **don't wrap every query in a try-catch**. This is a very common misconception that as soon as you started using exceptions you should start throwing tries and catches left and right. Quite contrary, try-catch should be used warily. While 99% of your errors shouldn't be handled in place, but rather by a site-wide error handler. You may read more on the topic from my article on [PHP error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting)

Comment: This is how it is now. I'm asking if it is possible to instruct MySQLi  driver to throw Exceptions, the same as you do with PDO.

Comment: Yes, your question is clear. But it's (a very) good practice to use a wrapper function to execute queries, once you have that, it's trivial to add those extra two lines.

Comment: The link for PHP error is down instead is [this](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors)

Answer (score 28):

> do I have to check if mysqli_query() returned false?

No.

You should be able to do what you require and instruct the mysqli driver to throw exceptions on SQL errors, but you will need to enable `MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR` if it is not already....

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT)
```

`mysqli_query()` should now throw exceptions on error. You do not need to check the return value for failure (which won't happen anyway because an exception is thrown).

```
public function mysqlQuery($SQL) {
    try {
        $this->Result = mysqli_query($this->DBlink, $SQL);
    } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
        throw new MySQLiQueryException($SQL, $e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
    }
    return $this->Result;
}
```

(NB: I changed `$this->SQL` to `$SQL` in the re-thrown exception.)

Comment: Is ti the fact that you are using mysqli_sql_exception` that allow the use of method $e->getCode()`, and that will reflect the $mysqli->errno i guess?

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier Yes, `getCode()` is a method of the `mysqli_sql_exception` object, so is only available in the scope of the catch block of that exception type.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a little too late, but for the sake of posterity. I find MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT to be to restrictive, certain exceptions where not be raised and hence they could not be handled by the catch block.

```
 mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL); // Traps all mysqli error 

 try {
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','user,'pwd','db');

     /* I don't need to explicitly throw an exception as this is being
      done automatically */

 } catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
 }
```

Comment: `Exception $e` will catch mysqli failure by itself or do we need to use `mysqli_sql_exception $e`? or are they equivalent? or is Exception used because of mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);`?

Comment: @LouisLogTrottier `Exception` object is the parent of all exceptions (`mysqli_sql_exception` is a subclass) so it will naturally catch _everything_.

Comment: `catch(Exception $e) {  echo $e->getMessage();` is a **useless cargo cult code**. If you take it out, the outcome will be **the same**: PHP reports uncaught exceptions already.